# Perform JOIN only on the last returned row in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join, greatest-n-per-group, outer-join

I have `table t1` which stores all requests. I have `table t2` which stores audits related to requests made in table t1.
In order to get latest audits for every request I need to perform join on the two tables.

I am able to perform JOIN using the following query:

```
SELECT 
    t2.id, t1.name, 
    t2.Msg
FROM 
    requests t1
    LEFT JOIN audits t2 ON t1.AuditId = t2.AuditId
ORDER BY t2.id DESC;
```

The above query is returning result as below:

```
id          Name            Msg      
56895415    ABC05           Message5
56895414    ABC05           Message4
56895413    ABC05           Message3
56895303    ABC04           Message5
56895302    ABC04           Message4
56895301    ABC04           Message3
```

I want to modify the query such that `only the last row(with highest id value)` is shown for every `t1.name`
In other words, my output should be as below:

```
id          Name            Msg      
56895415    ABC05           Message5
56895303    ABC04           Message5
```

Comment: Do you have a date/time indicator on audits table or some sort of row sequence which would indicate msg5 is the most recent?  (assuming you want most recent?)

Comment: The `id` in `table t1` provide row sequence where in the highest value of `id` for every `Name` has the latest message

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the query like below

```
SELECT 
    t2.id, t1.name, 
    t2.Msg
FROM 
    requests t1
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, Msg FROM audits ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) t2 ON t1.AuditId = t2.AuditId
ORDER BY t2.id DESC;
```

Comment: I think this would need to use a correlated sub-query in order to get all the auditIDs  since requests could have audit 1,2,3 etc...   but the derived table you're building would only return 1 row unless mysql supports an outer apply. using a left join that I don't know about.

Comment: This is not working as I am getting `null` for `id` and `Msg`

Comment: `id          Name            Msg      
null ABC05           null
null ABC04           null`

Comment: Derived table will act as a subquery when using with JOIN. It will always get the latest record for that particular AuditId

Comment: @meallhour can you please post your query dump here. As it should work!

Comment: You will get NULL only when the audit is not found for the request

Comment: `SELECT 
    t2.id, t1.name, 
    t2.Msg
FROM 
    requests t1
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, AuditId, Msg FROM audits ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) t2 ON t1.AuditId = t2.AuditId
ORDER BY t2.id DESC;` It should not be `NULL` as we have audits for all requests

Comment: Sorry i mean to say your table sql dump here so i can test locally

Comment: I have already given sample dump from my table in my question. `id          Name            Msg      
56895415    ABC05           Message5
56895414    ABC05           Message4
56895413    ABC05           Message3
56895303    ABC04           Message5
56895302    ABC04           Message4
56895301    ABC04           Message3`

Comment: Also, `t2.id` is primary key and it can never be null

Answer (score 0):

couple approaches:

Syntax on the below has not been verified: This is just "close" to what I'm thinking.  I'd need to recreate your tables/data to verify.

Get unique max ID's for each AuditID and join back to your query:

```
SELECT 
    t2.id, t1.name, 
    t2.Msg
FROM (SELECT max(ID) MID, AuditID
      FROM requests
      INNER JOIN Audits
      GROUP BY AuditID) t3
    INNER JOIN requests t1
       ON t3.AuditID= T1.AuditID
    LEFT JOIN audits t2 
       ON t1.AuditId = t2.AuditId
      AND T3.MID = T2.ID
ORDER BY t2.id DESC;
```

The other is to use a rowNumber variable per name sorting by ID descending then select only row 1 for each name.  Use this as your t2 and then join.
Depending on version of mySQL the analytic for this would be:

```
SELECT 
    t2.id, 
    t1.name, 
    t2.Msg
FROM requests t1
LEFT JOIN  (Select AuditID, msg, id, row_number() over (partition by AuditID ORDER BY id desc) rn) t2
  ON t1.AuditId = t2.AuditId
 and RN = 1
ORDER BY t2.id DESC;
```

but only 8.0+ I believe supports this syntax.

Comment: I am getting an error using the first approach - Error Code: 14. Can't change size of file (OS errno 28 - No space left on device)